# How to troubleshoot Xamarin Xaml related run-time errors?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Heyas, long time reading, first time posting.

My short question is, Is there an easy way to find problems with XAML in Xamarin? XAMLCompilation is not cutting it.

My long question - I have just spent the best part of a day struggling through an error with my XAML in Xamarin. Through some serious trial and error, essentially disassembling the app more than once to finally find the error in my XAML.  Looking at the problem afterwards, I really cant see from the information that I had that I could have found the problem.

The Offending Code -

```
    <TableView Intent="Form">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="Name" >
            <EntryCell Label="First Name" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <EntryCell Label="Last Name"  Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        </TableSection>
        <TableSection Title="Contact">
            <EntryCell Label="Phone" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"/>
            <EntryCell Label="Email" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
            <SwitchCell Text="Blocked" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBlocked}" />
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
```

In case you missed it the SwitchCell property to bind should be `on="{Binding IsBlocked}"`, rather than IsEnabled.

I am using XAMLC but this created an Android runtime error -

```
    04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: Process: ContactBookApp.Android, PID: 4219
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 1 more
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at (wrapper stelemref) System.Object:virt_stelemref_class (intptr,object)
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].Insert (System.Int32 index, T item) [0x0005f] in <8c304e4006094a46a7950338a3b3cb5d>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].InsertItem (System.Int32 index, T item) [0x00000] in <8c304e4006094a46a7950338a3b3cb5d>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].InsertItem (System.Int32 index, T item) [0x00006] in <8dac28ffb2cb41cba0b572038da86c99>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].Add (T item) [0x00023] in <8c304e4006094a46a7950338a3b3cb5d>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at Xamarin.Forms.TableSectionBase`1[T].Add (T item) [0x00000] in <42fe931976e64c199eddde45068a6c09>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at ContactBookApp.ContactDetailPage.InitializeComponent () [0x005f4] in <69ecbdf8eeeb43588bf41fa5db9c9afb>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at ContactBookApp.ContactDetailPage..ctor (ContactBookApp.Contact contact) [0x0001b] in <69ecbdf8eeeb43588bf41fa5db9c9afb>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:   at ContactBookApp.ContactsPage+<Contacts_ItemSelected>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00066] in <69ecbdf8eeeb43588bf41fa5db9c9afb>:0
04-18 13:49:27.395  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

This error does specify the page with the error `ContactDetailPage` But also the page that created it `ContactPage`. Ive spent time with the debugger in VS2017 but only get an unhandled exception. Also tried to troubleshoot with UWP build and received even less information. (how to find that?!?)

I'm only recently coding again after a 15 year hiatus and this is only tutorial exercises, but surely there is an easier way.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: It seems this message is the gist of it; System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.

Comment: Yeh, I rolled that but around my head for a while, but IsEnabled is still a boolean. the type matched?. but it may not be bindable i guess? Is this

Comment: What makes you think the problem is in the XAML? It seems the exception and XAML re two different problems

Comment: removing the line entirely, and also adding the correct property stopped the error from occurring . This is kind of my point though. Xaml is quite hard to troubleshoot once it had passed compilation.